# Asynchronous call is not hit when running jasmine test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test a javascript click event handler in which I have a  ajax(asynchronous) GET call which fetches the data from the server.
And I have all the business logic inside the done() function. When I keep debug pointer while running the jasmine test cases, I am seeing it is not at all hitting the done() logic .
How to handle this in Jasmine?

```
$('#setup').click(function () {

    $("div#spinner").addClass('spinner show');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/setup.cgi",
    }).done(function () {
        $("div#divLoadingSpinner").removeClass('spinner show');
        $('#setup').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

});

it("should disable clicking of Edit setup", function () {
  setup = $("#setup");
  setup.click();
  console.log(">>" + setup[0].attributes.length);
  expect(setup.attr('disabled')).toBeTruthy(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use deferred objects and resolve them to hit your success (done) scenario. See a sample below. Need not be exact, you can modify it as per your requirement.

```
spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (request) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.resolve(put your expected data here);
    return d.promise();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Type !!! . I found this . One more thing is , my response object will be changing based on the request . How to achieve this?

Comment: I did face that issue once :), for that I used conditional statements inside that function. i.e. if req == <X> then resolve <Y>  else resolve (or even reject) <Z>

Comment: When i check the request.url in the above function , it is always 'undefined'. So how can I make decision based on this?

Comment: hmm, I have never tried accessing URL inside that fake call. That request doesn't have it. that param can be used to call, success/fail scenarios. 
Can you try to check most recent calls and then get the url in it. i.e.     spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function (request) {
        var d = $.Deferred(); if ($.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]== "yourURL"){
        d.resolve(put your expected data here);} else {somethingelse}
        return d.promise();
    });

Comment: console.log("URL >>"+$.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0]["url"]); ...... This is always 'undefined' . How to get the exact URL ?

Comment: May I ask why you need URL in there ? What are you trying to do? Little more details please.